# How do I visualize labels of "many" categories at once?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've acquired information of which high schools our students are coming from, but the categories are so numerous that the ordinary coord_flip()-function is no longer helping. Is there another way of increasing readibility (increasing size of graph, increasing space between categories etc)?

In order to merge variable values (which will probably need to be done) I would first need to visualize the data in order to present it to my colleagues with necessary domain knowledge.

Here's a picture of my current plot:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
ggplot(fulldata,aes(x=fct_rev(fct_infreq(UPSEC_SCHOOL))))+geom_bar()+coord_flip()
```

And here's an excerpt of my data:

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776), class = "Date"), 
    UPSEC_SCHOOL = structure(c(1L, NA, 26L, 51L, NA, 3L, 71L, 
    52L, 58L, NA, 75L, 70L, 2L, 53L, 85L, 19L, 15L, 80L, 60L, 
    39L, 49L, 76L, 53L, 9L, 76L, 5L, 5L, 21L, 76L, 26L, 7L, 85L, 
    57L, 82L, 59L, 50L, 42L, 22L, 31L, 8L, 45L, 69L, 64L, 18L, 
    29L, 6L, 56L, 86L, 61L, 66L, 36L, NA, 46L, NA, 62L, NA, 83L, 
    48L, 41L, 55L, NA, NA, 74L, 84L, 55L, NA, 33L, NA, 38L, 32L, 
    67L, 79L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 16L, NA, 73L, NA, 10L, 10L, 23L, 
    77L, NA, 13L, 68L, 31L, 77L, 4L, 28L, 35L, 23L, 55L, 30L, 
    72L, 81L, 36L, NA, 55L, NA, NA, 22L, 65L, 22L, 65L, NA, 27L, 
    25L, NA, 43L, 62L, 37L, 30L, 11L, 17L, 23L, 30L, NA, 40L, 
    NA, 62L, NA, 63L, 30L, NA, 62L, 78L, 62L, 34L, NA, 22L, 47L, 
    14L, 17L, 72L, 30L, 54L, 22L, NA, 30L, 17L, 24L, 20L, 33L, 
    44L, 12L, 30L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("AGNEBERGSGYMNASIET                       ", 
    "Ale gymnasium", "Angeredsgymnasiet", "Angeredsgymnasiet 2           ", 
    "Aranäsgymnasiet", "Aranäsgymnasiet Enhet 3       ", "Bräckegymnasiet", 
    "Cybergymnasiet Göteborg", "De la Gardiegymnasiet", "De la Gardiegymnasiet, enhet 1", 
    "De la Gardiegymnasiet, enhet 3", "Drottning Blanka Gymn. GTB    ", 
    "Drottning Blankas Gymn Trollhä", "Drottning Blankas Gymn. Kba   ", 
    "Elof Lindälvs gymnasium", "Falkenbergs Gymnasieskola 5   ", 
    "Folkuniv Gymnasium Trollhättan", "Fyrisskolan", "Fässbergsgymnasiet", 
    "Gislaveds gymn NA, SAM, Vård  ", "Gislaveds gymnasium/komvux", 
    "GTI:s gymnasieskola           ", "Gullmarsgymnasiet 2           ", 
    "Hagströmska gymnasiet Falun   ", "Handelsak. Yrkesh. o Gymnasium", 
    "Hulebäcksgymnasiet", "Hulebäcksgymnasiet 3          ", "Hulebäcksgymnasiet 4          ", 
    "Hulebäcksgymnasiet 5          ", "Hvitfeldtska gymnasiet 1      ", 
    "Hvitfeldtska gymnasiet 3      ", "HÄRNÖSANDS GYMNASIUM 2", 
    "JENSEN Gymnasium Göteborg     ", "Karlbergsgymnasiet 2          ", 
    "Katedralskolan                ", "Katrinelundsgymnasiet 1       ", 
    "Katrinelundsgymnasiet 4       ", "KATRINELUNDSGYMNASIET 5", 
    "KCK-Karlbergsgymnasiet", "Kitas Gymnasium               ", 
    "Kitas Natur                   ", "KUNGL SV. BALETSKOLAN GY", 
    "Kunskapsgymnasiet Göteborg    ", "Lagmansgymnasiet              ", 
    "LERUMS GYMNASIUM, SKOLENHET 1", "LERUMS GYMNASIUM, SKOLENHET 2", 
    "LERUMS GYMNASIUM, SKOLENHET 4", "Lichron Teknikgymn.Trollhättan", 
    "Lindeskolan", "Ljud & Bildskolan LBS Halmstad", "Lärcentrum komvux         ", 
    "Lärcentrum/komvux         ", "Magnus Åbergsgymnasiet", "Mikael Elias Gymn, Göteborg   ", 
    "Mimers Hus Gymnasium 2        ", "Mimers Hus Gymnasium 4        ", 
    "MIMERS HUS GYMNASIUM 6", "Nils Ericsonsgymnasiet", "Nils Ericsonsgymnasiet 4", 
    "NTI-gymnasiet Karlskrona", "NÖSNÄSGYMNASIET 2", "NÖSNÄSGYMNASIET 3", 
    "NÖSNÄSGYMNASIET 4", "Peder Skrivares sk Sektor 1b  ", "Plusgymnasiet i Göteborg      ", 
    "Plusgymnasiet i Uddevalla     ", "Polhemsgymnasium 2            ", 
    "Porthälla gymnasium/Högskolef ", "Rosendalsgymnasiet            ", 
    "S:t Eskils gymnasium", "Schillerska gymnasiet", "Schillerska gymnasiet 2       ", 
    "Sigrid Rudebecks gymnasium    ", "SKF Tekniska Gymnasium        ", 
    "Sundsta/Älvkullegymnasiet", "Uddevalla gymnasieskola", "UDDEVALLA GYMNASIESKOLA EK", 
    "UDDEVALLA GYMNASIESKOLA EK-SPINT-AGB", "UDDEVALLA GYMNASIESKOLA HA", 
    "UDDEVALLA GYMNASIESKOLA SA", "Uddevalla gymnasieskola SA    ", 
    "UDDEVALLA GYMNASIESKOLA TE-IN", "Vadsbogymnasiet               ", 
    "Wisbygymnasiet Söder", "VUXENUTBILDNINGEN GÖTEBORG", "VuxenUtbildningsCentrum   "
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -154L), groups = structure(list(
    start_date = structure(17776, class = "Date"), .rows = list(
        1:154)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You can display only the first values. An other idea is to make a `wordcloud` but less professional.

Comment: Hrrrm, I managed to increase the figure size in Rmarkdown so I could actually read/present it. Not very elegant perhaps but workable.

Comment: You can increase resolutions with `ggsave`, e.g. `ggsave('/path/to/output/file', scale = 2)`. When scaling like this I'd also increase the size of the text with `theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20)` or whatever value helps you see what you're trying to do.